# How to get the topics that have most answers by Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, eloquent-relationship

I'm working on a forum project using Laravel 9 and for this project, there is a One To Many relationship between Question & Answer:

**`Question.php`** Model:

```
public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class,'ans_que_id');
    }
```

And this is for **`Answer`** Model:

```
public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class);
    }
```

Now **I want to get the questions that has the most answers.**

But I don't know how to do that, so if you know, please let me know...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withCount()`([Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)) then sort by them

example:

```
Question::query()->withCount('answers')->orderByDesc('answers_count')->get();
```